# how to call a script file or executable from Python on Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

If I call a script file from Python interpreter or a Python script, I get the error `'No such file or directory'` and the Linux script does not execute.
If I call pure Linux commands, like   subprocess.call('ls')   it works fine.

In 'C',  I would use:   system("");

What is the equivalent in Python?

From my Python script, on a Linux computer, I need to call scripts that do builds.
`subprocess.call` works great for Linux shell commands, but I get `'No such file or directory'` when I call a script.

Here's my Python script line that calls:

```
    rtn_code = subprocess.call(['~/WindRiver/workspace/XPedite5570_SMP_VIP/build_MM_VxWorks'])

`build_MM_VxWorks` is a Linux script that uses VxWorks development tools to build a VxWorks kernel.

`build_MM_VxWorks` works okay from the Linux command line.
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying an absolute path instead of using `~/` notation?

Comment: ~ is a feature of the shell. If you don't invoke a shell, you don't have it.

Comment: You can approximate the behavior of ~ by reading the value of `os.environ['HOME']` or `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir`.

Comment: @FatalError There's also `os.path.expanduser`

Comment: This works:
import os
os.system('./myscript')
also
os.system('~/primary/experiments/myscript')

however,
import subprocess
subprocess.call('./myscript')
...does not work.  Why?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try out [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) . It simulates shell user-input on a high level. It might be a bit "hacky", but it is very powerful when you need to automate working procedure.

Here is how I use it to read a table in a database:

```
import pexpect, getpass

child = pexpect.spawn('mysql -u root -p')
child.expect('Enter password: ')
password = getpass.getpass("Enter Mysql password for user root \n")
child.sendline(password)
child.sendline("use database")

child.expect('Database changed')

child.sendline('SELECT * FROM table;')
child.interact()
```

As you see, it is very easy to mimic user input.